# How do I programatically remove a flash drive based on its device node name?

Tags: c++, linux, usb, usb-flash-drive

I have a Linux system with multiple USB flash drives plugged in, as /dev/sda1, /dev/sdb1, etc.  I need to eject one of these from within my program -- something like `EjectDrive("/dev/sdb1");`  I then may need to programmatically re-insert the drive.

I know I can do this from the command line if I know the USB bus, port and device number.  e.g. `echo '2-1.3' > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind` and then `echo '2-1.3' > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind`

I'm not sure how to do this from C++, and be 100% sure I am using the correct bus, port and device for the specified drive.

This is an embedded platform with BusyBox v1.22.1, so udev is not available to me, and lsusb returns minimal information.

Comment: There's slways the `eject` program..

Comment: So there is.  But I also (may) need to programmatically re-insert it, so that only solves half of my problem.  I will edit the question to make that clear.  Thank you.

Comment: Have you explored man pages?  What is the command to list the USB drives on the system, if any?  (use google)  So how do you know the bus, port, device?  How do you find out when you don't know? (hint - google "how do i list all usb devices?)  Perhaps you might do more research ... there are other resources for these questions, but none of these are C++

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can be done using libusb (follow [this link](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/148707-introduction-to-using-libusb-10/) for libusb usage with C++). Now a few things to keep in mind -

1 - What is the device address? (You can get this using libusb API)

```
libusb_get_device_list (libusb_context *ctx, libusb_device ***list)
libusb_get_device_address (libusb_device *dev)
libusb_get_port_number (libusb_device *dev)
```

2 - Is the device connected to the root hub port or to a hub port? (This can be done by reading the parent device of the /dev/sdb1 or sda1)

```
libusb_get_parent (libusb_device *dev)
```

3 - If its connected to a hub, then do a control transfer to "clear" PORT_POWER feature of that port. That will turn off the port and the device will be disconnected. You can "set" PORT_POWER feature to turn on the port and the device will be connected again. Remember that you will not get any disconnect event which is as per the spec. (EHCI or XHCI)

```
int libusb_control_transfer (   libusb_device_handle *  dev_handle,
uint8_t     bmRequestType,
uint8_t     bRequest,
uint16_t    wValue,
uint16_t    wIndex,
unsigned char *     data,
uint16_t    wLength,
unsigned int    timeout 
)
```

4 - If the device is connected to the root hub port directly, then please check if libusb supports clearing root hub port power. I am not sure about this. This also depends on the Host controller driver stack.

Please follow the link I mentioned at the top for example usage of these API's.

Comment: This could be a great answer if it mentioned the actual `libusb` APIs that could be used. A minimal code-snippet (even if it was only verified on a particular hw/sw setup) that demonstartes identifying an USB device by its device-node name and "ejecting" it, is what is missing in this answer.

Comment: @TheCodeArtist Thanks for the suggestion. Added the APIs.